# I have to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac1x=-\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac 1x = - \infty,$$ but I am fundamentally stuck on where to start with the problem.

The definition says that for a left-handed limit $L$ of $f$ at $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in A$, where $c \in A \cap (-\infty,c) = \{ x \in A : x < c \} $, with $0 < c-x < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

I also know that I have to involve an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ in order to show that $f(x) < \alpha$ which implies that it is tending toward $-\infty$. I sort have started with noting, clearly for $\alpha > 0$ then $1/x > \alpha$, but I don't know what to do for the other case.

Comment: This is equivalent to showing $\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac 1y = + \infty$, with $x=-y$

Comment: Right, I am just really not sure how to go about either.

Comment: Show that for all $~c < 0, ~$ there exists a $~\delta > 0~$ such that $-\delta < x < 0~$ implies that $~\dfrac{1}{x} < c.~$

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, let us pay attention to the definitions involved:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}f(x) = -\infty & \Longleftrightarrow (\forall M\in\mathbb{R}_{> 0})(\exists\delta_{M}\in\mathbb{R}_{> 0})(\forall x\in D_{f})(-\delta_{M} < x < 0 \Rightarrow f(x) < -M)
\end{align*}

In the present case $f(x) = 1/x$. More precisely, here is the follow-up definition:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}f(x) = -\infty & \Longleftrightarrow (\forall M\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists\delta_{M}\in\mathbb{R}_{> 0})(\forall x\in D_{f})(-\delta_{M} < x < 0 \Rightarrow 1/x < -M)
\end{align*}

Consequently, for every $x\in(-\delta_{M},0)$, one concludes that:
\begin{align*}
-\delta_{M} < x < 0 \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{x} > \frac{1}{\delta_{M}} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} < -\frac{1}{\delta_{M}}
\end{align*}

Hence, for every $M > 0$, it suffices to take $\delta_{M} = 1/M$.

Hopefully this helps!